# Problems importing component ej from grid syncfusion using the react

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion

I'm using the react and I want in one of my components to render a syncfusion grid. However I have problems with one of the components of the grid. The grid component ej is not found. I've tried importing in a number of ways but I was not successful. Has anyone had this problem and found a solution? [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRZZl.png)

Example code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
//This import does not find the component (ej) needed to render the grid
import  {ej} from "syncfusion-javascript";
//There are scripts in the index.html file to mount the grid according to 
the Syncfusion documentation

class GridSeries extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.menuGrid = this.menuGrid.bind(this);
}

//Function responsible for mounting the grid it is called inside my render method
menuGrid() {
    $(function () {
        $("#Grid").ejGrid({
            dataSource: teste,
            allowPaging: true,
            allowSorting: true,
            allowGrouping: true,
            allowFiltering: true,
            allowReordering: true,
            allowMultiSorting: true,
            filterSettings: {filterType: "excel"},
            toolbarSettings: {showToolbar: true, toolbarItems: [ej.Grid.ToolBarItems.ExcelExport, ej.Grid.ToolBarItems.WordExport, ej.Grid.ToolBarItems.PdfExport]},
            columns: [
                {type: "checkbox", width: 50},
                {field: "OrderID", headerText: "Order ID", width: 75, textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Right},
                {field: "CustomerID", headerText: "Customer ID", width: 80},
                {field: "EmployeeID", headerText: "Employee ID", width: 75, textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Right},
                {field: "Freight", width: 75, format: "{0:C}", textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Right},
                {field: "OrderDate", headerText: "Order Date", width: 80, format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Right},
                {field: "ShipCity", headerText: "Ship City", width: 110}
            ],
            toolbarClick: function (e) {
                this.exportGrid = this["export"];
                if (e.itemName == "Excel Export") {
                    this.exportGrid(window.baseurl + 'api/grid/ExcelExport')
                    e.cancel = true;
                } else if (e.itemName == "Word Export") {
                    this.exportGrid(window.baseurl + 'api/grid/WordExport')
                    e.cancel = true;
                } else if (e.itemName == "PDF Export") {
                    this.exportGrid(window.baseurl + 'api/grid/PdfExport')
                    e.cancel = true;
                    document.getElementById('container')
                }
            },
        });
    });

    //Test Base
    var teste = [
        {Name: "bruno", City: "Brasilia"},
        {Name: "bruno1", City: "Riacho Fundo l"},
        {Name: "bruno2", City: "Guára"},
        {Name: "bruno3", City: "Cruzeiro"}
    ];
}
render() {
    return (
            <div className="content-container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="cols-mple-area">
                        { this.menuGrid()}
                        <div id="Grid"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            );
   }
}

export default GridSeries;
```

Comment: Please try asking your question in English or on the [Portuguese Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English - this is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site!

Comment: Post code usage example.

Comment: @Chase DeAnda     codigo postad

Comment: Did you run through the installation process here? https://help.syncfusion.com/js/installation-and-deployment#configuring-syncfusion-npm-packages

Comment: @Chase DeAnda I follow all these directions. I installed the Syncfusion JavaScript library with npm according to the tutorial. It is in my node modules folder, but I can not do the import. The way it is imported in the example I posted does not work.

Comment: Try to remove the `{ }` around it. Where did you get the import syntax from?

Comment: @Chase DeAnda Yes I tried without the parenthesis too but the error continues

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue is that you have load the scripts from node package and we can’t load the require scripts from the node package in the react component by default. So, we suggest you to use either webpack or browserify technique to achieve your requirement. Please refer to the below knowledge base document.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7547/how-to-bundle-syncfusion-reactjs-components-using-webpack-and-browserify

Comment: The architecture I use is the react-script that is different from the one proposed by the link. I do not use a webpack configuration file. The webpack settings are implied. The architecture I use will dry this premise:
Https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts

Comment: The documentation to get React working with SyncFusion is rather confusing. I'm still working through the same issues you describe. I haven't found the solution quite  yet.